# jquery inside User Control created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I've created an `User Control` where I have a button. And when this button is clicked a jquery function is executed. The jquery function is inside the `User Control` page.

Now i'm trying to add this User Control dynamically in my page, inside an `UpdatePanel`.
The problem is that my button is not working.

After i google it, i found out that maybe the problem is in using jquery inside ajax `UpdatePanel`. After every asynchronous postback the jquery script is lost. So the idea is to rebind my jquery function in every asyn postback. But in the all answers that i found, they kinda suppose that the script manager is in User control and it's not in my case.

Here my jquery fucntion

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= idButtonLeft %>").bind("click", function () {
            var options = $("#<%= idListDestinataire %> option:selected");
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                $(options[i]).remove();
                $("#<%= idListSource %>").append(opt);
            }
        });
        $("#<%= idButtonRight %>").bind("click", function () {
            var options = $("#<%= idListSource %> option:selected");
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                $(options[i]).remove();
                $("#<%= idListDestinataire %>").append(opt);
            }
        });
    });



</script>
```

the code to add my User control dynamically

```
     Dim CListBox As UserControl = LoadControl("DragDropList.ascx")
        CListBox.ID = "CListBox" + i.ToString()
        CType(CListBox, DragDropList).idListSource = "ListLeft" + i.ToString()
        CType(CListBox, DragDropList).idListDestinataire = "ListRight" + i.ToString()
        CType(CListBox, DragDropList).idButtonLeft = "idButtonLeft" + i.ToString()
        CType(CListBox, DragDropList).idButtonRight = "idButtonRight" + i.ToString()

        UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(CListBox)
        Panel1.Controls.Add(CListBox)
```

in my page i have this

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        </asp:Panel>

                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButton1" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageAlign="Right" EnableViewState="false" ImageUrl=".\image\ajouter.png"  runat="server"  AlternateText="Ajouter" OnClick="AjouterC"/>
```

So please any ideas to help.
Thank you

When i changed the trigger on PostBackTrigger, it's working but i want it in asynchrone postback. and still don't know why it's not working!

Comment: Please some code.... and an example of what you may look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570839/jquery-auto-complete-extender-not-working-after-postback/12571703#12571703

Comment: Have a look at delegated events in jquery.

Comment: @Aristos : Sorry, i had a look on it i don't think it's the same problem

Comment: @RobSchmuecker : can u please explain further what do you mean?

Comment: i edited my post..thank u to take a look on it!

Comment: I'm really not familiar with ASP, please can you just show the generated HTML and Javascript?

Comment: just put your button which you want to call jquery function, ouside the update panel...@yuiichan

Comment: @SmartKiller : but the button is already in the UserControl that im adding in the UpdatePanel..

Comment: don't add userControl inside update panel...just put it outside update panel....then try...@yuiichan

Comment: @SmartKiller: i  ve already try it..it's working but the problem is when im adding it dynamically

Comment: just briefly explain how you add user control dynamically @yuiichan

Comment: what do you want to know exactly please because i have already put in the post the code that im using to add my UserControl

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
                $(function () {
                    //Your script
                });
            }
        }
</script>
```

This will work on post back that your update panel is giving to you.

Comment: in the script of the jquery function inside my UserControl

Comment: but i did #<%= idButtonLeft %> so that everytime i add my UserControl in the page the buttons inside each one would be independant..And i defined this idButtonLeft like a proprety of the UserControl

Comment: you can use with $("#<%= idButtonLeft %>").bind and ("#idButtonLeft").bind also, but if you do not want to remove then try to use javascript as i said above.

Comment: can u please explain further what do u mean by using javascript?

Comment: Whole script below <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> this script it's a javascript that you need to put it in your main page rather then using it into the user control

Comment: but this script is for just one UserControl..what i mean is how can we call the same jquery function for the others UserControl added dynamically because when the page is loaded we just know the IDs of the static controls

Comment: create one java script file place this inside the file and use reference to all pages whenever you required the javascript