# Asp .net ajax autocomplete not working. Webmethod is not getting called

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Can somebody tell me why WebMethod is not firing in one page alone, this same code works in another page, but not in the page which i want it to work. I shifted this entire code into a new page and it works perfectly fine there, but if i use it in my actual page, it doesn't fire the webmethod. Not sure what's happening.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtSkill]").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<% =ResolveUrl("HRMCareerEAF.aspx/GetSkills") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=hfSkillID]").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
    </script>

                                                                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtSkill" runat="server" style="text-align: center" />
```

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string[] GetSkills(string prefix)
    {
        HRMRecruitmentProcessDAL obj = new HRMRecruitmentProcessDAL();
        DataSet ds = obj.BindMstcommon(HttpContext.Current.Session["CandidateID"].ToString(), "GetSkillsDD", "%" + prefix + "%");
        List<string> skills = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            skills.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Skill_Desc"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["skill_id"].ToString() + "|" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Skill_GroupID"].ToString())); //ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Skill_GroupDesc"].ToString() + " : " +
        }
        return skills.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Any errors on server or browser? "not working" doesn't say much - clearly it doesn't work, or you wouldn't be asking a question

Comment: Show us the error in alert. You might wanna put alert in every steps to debug

Comment: Autocomplete doesn't show up below my textbox, but it shows if i shift this code to a new page. When i tried debugging, i understood that my webmethod is not getting called when i type something in my textbox.

Comment: @PrasanthKumar is your Jquerymethod calling? and also did you tried using without  ResolveUrl ?

Comment: How do i try without Resolveurl, i am new to jqery. On pageload jquerymethod is getting called.

Comment: @PrasanthKumar something like this  `url: "HRMCareerEAF.aspx/GetSkills"`

Comment: Tried jus now, still same problem, webmethod not getting fired.

Comment: I tried moving jquery method to <head>, then iam getting this error 
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Can you go to console  and check what error you are getting and you can write Url like this `'HRMCareerEAF.aspx/GetSkills'`  no need to `<% =ResolveUrl("HRMCareerEAF.aspx/GetSkills") %>`

Comment: Hi All, thank you soo much for the support, i tried many things, my skills textbox is inside an asp:multiview, if i put the textbox in asp:multiview's first view, i.,e the one with index '0', autocomplete works perfectly, but if i move it to any other view other than the one with index '0', it doesn't work. Any workaround for this?

Comment: @PrasanthKumar add this as diff question , if your existing resolved , then will make it as answer and post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you soo much for the support.
I found out the problem and solution.

Actual problem is that auto complete doesn't work after partial page postback and my txtskill is in 3rd view of asp:multiview which refreshes only the part of page inside my updatepanel.

Jquery methods do not bind if the page postbacks partially. I got solution in the following link.

[Jquery Auto complete extender not working after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570839/jquery-auto-complete-extender-not-working-after-postback)

My altered code is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          SetAutoComplete();
      });
      $(document).ready(function () {
          var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
          prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
          prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

          // Place here the first init of the autocomplete
          SetAutoComplete();
      });

      function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
      }

      function EndRequest(sender, args) {
          // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init the Autocomplete
          SetAutoComplete();
      }
      function SetAutoComplete() {
          $("[id$=txtSkill]").autocomplete({
              source: function (request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                      url: '<% =ResolveUrl("HRMCareerEAF.aspx/GetSkills") %>',
                      data: JSON.stringify({ prefix: request.term }),
                      dataType: "json",
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      success: function (data) {
                          response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                              return {
                                  label: item.split('-')[0],
                                  val: item.split('-')[1]
                              };
                          }))
                      }
                  });
              },
              select: function (e, i) {
                  $("[id$=hfSkillID]").val(i.item.val);
              },
              minLength: 1
          });
      }
    </script>
```

Thank yo soo much for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check few things

1) check if you are able to call the api using rest api testing tools like postman

2) If you are able to access it can you please check if web developer tool console if it has any error like 404(Not found) or 500(Internal server error)

3) Modify your

```
data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
```

to

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ prefix: request.term }),
```

Please check value of '<% =ResolveUrl("HRMCareerEAF.aspx/GetSkills") %>'

Also I am not sure but try getting rid of (EnableSession = true).